# php site to create certificates (CSR) and (CRT)

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate, crt, csr

I need to create a website in PHP to create CSR and CRT.

I can't use exec, system, or similars.

How can i do? I have a web form with the data to create a CSR.

I hope you can help me please.

Best regards.

Comment: without command line access you cant. if your on a host that does not allow this contact them, they will have to do it for you - or move hosts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288305/how-does-one-install-ssl-certificates-programatically-openssl guess it is possible, if potentially dangerous

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed. In any event.. http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#csr is an example of how to do CSRs. I have no idea what a CRT is. In the context of RSA private key generation it'd mean Chinese Remainder Theorem but in your case? I have no clue lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the OpenSSL Extension.  You should be able to do what you need given the small amount of information you provided.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php